# How can i remove empty columns from asp.net column chart?

Tags: asp.net, charts

i have an asp.net column chart. in my X axis i have three column (1,4,5) 
. when chart is shown there are two other empty columns:2 ,3 . i don't want to see them. I just need 1,4, and 5. Next To each Other. without Interval. I have not set any Interval!!! is it possible?

My data source is a simple table, with two columns. 
thanks  [My Chart Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AseKX.png)

```
 Chart2.Series[0].YValueMembers = "c";
 Chart2.Series[0].XValueMember = "q";
 var list = rl.sp_ChartDakheli(QNumer, Dp_FilterType.SelectedValue,Dp_NiazType.SelectedValue,  int.Parse(Dp_FilterFileds.SelectedValue), 5);       
  Chart1.DataSource = list;
  Chart1.DataBind();

            <asp:Chart ID="Chart2" runat="server" 
              BackGradientStyle="TopBottom" BackImageTransparentColor="Transparent" 
                BackSecondaryColor="White" BorderColor="#1A3B69" BorderDashStyle="Solid" 
                BorderlineColor="Transparent" BorderWidth="2px" Height="488px" Palette="None" 
                PaletteCustomColors="Red; Blue; Yellow; 0, 192, 0; Fuchsia; Aqua; 255, 128, 0; Silver; 255, 192, 192; AliceBlue" 
          Width="1100px"    >
                <Series>
                    <asp:Series Name="Series1" Color="Blue" CustomProperties="PixelPointWidth=50">
                    </asp:Series>
                </Series>
                <ChartAreas>
                    <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1" BackColor="Transparent" BackSecondaryColor="White" 
                        ShadowColor="Transparent">


                    </asp:ChartArea>
                </ChartAreas>
            </asp:Chart>
```

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Can you upload a screenshot of the issue and also post your code that populates the chart with information?

Comment: Thanks For your ATTENTION "FRIENDS"!! i find it by my self!! XValueIndexed=true;